# What does `typename` keyword in reinterpret_cast function call do?

Tags: c++, templates, typename

In https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/dc2cdeae68a6ffc6be24a9dee75ccea745936657/aten/src/ATen/native/quantized/cpu/qupsample_nearest2d.cpp#L40, we see `typename` used in the function call to the template function `reinterpret_cast`.

I've never seen a function call where the `typename` keyword was used.

I tried this with a simple code but the program doesn't compile:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T i) {
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  func<typename int> func(1);
}
```

```
test.cpp:19:17: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
  func<typename int> func(1);
```

Comment: @user17732522 hmm, but there weren't any compiler errors in the PR that I linked, so it seems it compiled fine

Comment: I meant that the code in your question is not valid C++. `typename` can only appear before a qualified-id. In the linked code the context is a very different one. The duplicate explains when it is allowed and required.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<typename scalar_t::underlying*>(idata);` and `func<typename int> func(1);` are two completly different things.  I've closed this as a duplcuate that explains why `typename` is needed in code you saw.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is a keyword, not a function. Now a cast-expression looks a lot like a function call expression, so the confusion is understandable. As an example of the differences, functions have addresses but `reinterpret_cast` does not.

Comment: Key phrase from the error message: "qualified name". A qualified name will have `::` in it. An unqualified name will not.